# git error: There are still logs under

Tags: git

I am trying to use `git fetch --all` but it gives me errors when fetching a certain repository.

> error: There are still logs under '.git/logs/refs/remotes/tpickel/RS'

and

> **!** [new branch] RS -> tpickel/RS (unable to update local ref)

What went wrong and how to fix it?

[image: git error]

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Apparently there used to be a `tpickel/RS/foo` (for some name `foo`).

Your Git recorded information about that, in `.git/logs/refs/remotes/tpickel/RS/foo`.  Now your Git is trying to create a file named `.git/logs/refs/remotes/tpickel/RS`, which will record information about the new branch `tpickel/RS`.  It cannot do so because there is a *directory*, `.git/logs/refs/remotes/tpickel/RS`, in the way.  The in-the-way directory contains some file (`foo`, or some other name, there's nothing above to show what the actual name is), which is how your Git was keeping a reflog for `tpickel/RS/foo`.

Now that remote branch `tpickel/RS` is gone, your Git needs to remove both `refs/remotes/tpickel/RS/foo` and its reflog file.  Ideally, `git fetch --prune tpickel` will do both of those all at once for you, *before* trying to also create `tpickel/RS` and its reflog, which is what is failing because of the lingering `tpickel/RS/foo`.

If the `--prune` works, you're done.  If not, you will have to go in to `.git/logs/refs/remotes/tpickel/` and either remove all of the `RS` and `RS/*` entries, or rename them to get them out of the way.  (If you want to save these, despite the remote `tpickel` having dropped the branch, move them rather than deleting them, and don't let `git fetch --prune` delete them.  You probably do not want to save them though.)

#### What `--prune` means

When you run `git fetch remote` (such as `git fetch tpickel`), Git contacts the named *`remote`* and gets from it a list of all its references.  You can view this list yourself at any time by running `git ls-remote remote`: this invokes the same start but then stops after getting the list, rather than continuing on to do the fetch.

Suppose that (as is the normal default case) your Git is instructed to copy all their branch references to remote-tracking branches.  In this particular example, that would mean copying `refs/heads/master` to `refs/remotes/tpickel/master`, for instance.  This kind of copying is generally additive: if remote `tpickel` has branches `master` and `develop` today, and tomorrow they add `feature`, you will have two remote-tracking branches today and you will add a new one tomorrow when you fetch their `feature`.  At some point, though, they may *remove* a branch.  What if they remove `feature` when you are still using `refs/remotes/tpickel/feature`?

Git's answer to this puzzle is to default to keeping any copied reference forever.  As you have just seen, this can sometimes gets in the way of new branches after old branches have been removed, so this solution is not at all perfect.  What adding `--prune` does is to take the complete list, compare it to your set of remote-tracking branches, and *delete* from your local repository any remote-tracking branch that has no corresponding branch on the remote.  That is, just because we had copied *their* `refs/heads/develop` to *our* `refs/remotes/tpickel/develop` yesterday, does not mean we should *keep* `refs/remotes/tpickel/develop` today, if *their* `refs/heads/develop` is gone.  So if you specify `--prune`, Git looks for such occurrences and deletes any stale remote-tracking branches.

This code has been around for a while (since 1.7 or so I think).  Git version 1.8.5 added two configuration items: `fetch.prune` and `remote.remote.prune` (e.g., `remote.tpickel.prune`).  If `fetch.prune` is set to `true`, `git fetch` always prunes; if the specific remote's configuration is set to `true`, `git fetch` prunes that specific remote.

(The code was improved a bit in version 2.0.0 of Git to handle potential ambiguous mappings.  This covers cases where multiple upstream references can potentially map to the same remote-tracking reference.  With normal setups, this never happens: it can only occur if you make up your own `fetch` entries for some named remote.)

Comment: `--prune` did not work, i had to delete it manually. thank you for the help. you maybe want to give or link an explanation of what `prune` exactly does

Comment: It's interesting that the `git fetch --prune` failed.  Too late now but it would have been even more interesting to test `git remote update --prune tpickel` and see if *that* worked, and which version of Git you have: reportedly, some version(s) have some bug(s) where one works and the other does not.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation! Running `git fetch --prune <remote>` fixed my issue.

Comment: In case this helps anyone: I had this same issue - `--prune` did not work for me, turns out I had a folder `ZZ-1234` (note upper case) under `.git\logs\refs\remotes\origin` and a new branch `zz-1234` (note lower case) had at some later time been created on origin. I manually deleted my folder and then git pull (and fetch) worked. I assume the case difference (I'm on Windows) is what threw the original `git fetch --prune` off.

Comment: @DaveMarley's explanation can help people on Mac (or Windows?) which has a case insensitive file system by default. A colleague on Linux (or case sensitive mac) can brick your repo by creating branches `foo/bar` and `FOO`. You will need to fix the remote, e.g. deleting `FOO`: `git push origin :FOO`.

Answer (score 35):

Running "rm -rf .git/logs" solved my problem.

⚠️ Please note if you try this solution, all of your stashed changes would be gone

Comment: Please note if you try this solution, all of your stashed changes would be gone

Comment: Note to self, "read important comments too!". ;(

Comment: If you want to be safe then just go to .git folder and rename the logs folder instead

Comment: I think this answer is dangerous. You only provide a command with no explanation.

Answer (score 11):

I had similar issue, deleting `.git/logs/refs/remotes/tpickel/RS/foo` resolved it

Comment: Yes, except I went more defensive and just renamed the folder.

Comment: Most pinpoint answer with quick solution..